# How to fix a channel disconnected exception in druid when submiting a indexing task

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, druid

I'm submitting an indexing task to druid but the task never starts an is repeatedly logging the following:

```
WARN [main] io.druid.indexing.common.actions.RemoteTaskActionClient - Exception submitting action for task[index_wikipedia_2019-02-13T18:14:20.653Z]
org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Channel disconnected
```

Versions used:

- HDP 2.6.3.0
- Druid 0.10.1

Comment: Please provide overlord.log which has more details about your task and what is wrong with it

Comment: check the idletimeout. It should be increased.

Comment: Thank you all, I've realized that the issue was the usage of excluded paths in combination with the kerberization. Once I've blank the excludePath property, the Kerberos ticket started to work properly and the Channel Disconnected dissapeared.